# Can't install ros-hydro-rosjava

Tags: ros, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to run the rosjava install as shown on the ros wiki. When I run this line...

```
> sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-catkin ros-hydro-ros ros-hydro-rosjava python-wstool
```

I can't get ros-hydro-rosjava to install. The site states....

```
If the metapackage ros-hydro-rosjava is not yet in the public repository, install rosjava-build-tools, rosjava-bootstrap, rosjava-messages, rosjava-core, rosjava-extras and zeroconf-jmdns-suite yourself manually.
```

I've gotten rosjava-bootstram and rosjava-build-tool working through this line

```
> sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rosjava-build-tools ros-hydro-rosjava-bootstrap
```

But I still need the others... where can I find these and get them installed?

I've tried running the source installation, but it doesn't work when I try to access the git repository. It claims my wstool gets an error.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/84591/can%27t-install-ros-hydro-rosjava/) by [Hoser117](https://answers.ros.org/users/7221/hoser117/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-09-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ros-hydro-rosjava package is not still in the deb public server, so you can

1. If you are not in a hurry, wait a
   bit until it arrives; you can check
   here:

   `http://www.ros.org/debbuild/hydro.html`

   retry apt-get install ros-hydro-rosjava when the red squares
   disappear.
2. If you cannot wait, add shadow-fix server to your package sources. In      /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list, replace

   `deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main`

   by

   `deb http://packages.ros.org/ros-shadow-fixed/ubuntu precise main`

   then apt-get update and retry apt-get install ros-hydro-rosjava

Btw, what error you get when installing from sources?

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2013-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0